# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added :

Tags: java, android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

so I have a BottomNavigation that have another TabLayout in some menu, when i click that menu it got me error like a title.
here's my code

**FavoriteFragment**

which contain fragment in BottomNavigation

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {

public FavoriteFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    setViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_favorite);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    sectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new MoviesFavoriteFragment(),getResources().getString(R.string.title_movies));
    sectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new TvShowFavoriteFragment(),getResources().getString(R.string.title_tv_show));
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
}
}
```

And i got pageradapter for my ViewPager

**SectionsPagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> listFragment = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> titleFragment = new ArrayList<>();

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return listFragment.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listFragment.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
    listFragment.add(fragment);
    titleFragment.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titleFragment.get(position);
}
}
```

And this is some fragment in TabLayout which got the error

**MoviesFavoriteFragment**

```
public class MoviesFavoriteFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerAdapterFavMovies adapterFavMovies;

public MoviesFavoriteFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies_favorite, container, false);


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    RecyclerView rv_fav_movie = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_fav_movies);
    rv_fav_movie.setHasFixedSize(true);

    rv_fav_movie.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));

    adapterFavMovies = new RecyclerAdapterFavMovies(view.getContext());
    rv_fav_movie.setAdapter(adapterFavMovies);

    ArrayList<Movies> listMovie = (ArrayList<Movies>) loadDataFavoriteMovies();

    MainViewModel mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    mainViewModel.setFavMovies(listMovie);
    mainViewModel.getMovieList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),getMovies);
}

private List<Movies> loadDataFavoriteMovies(){
    MovieDatabase database = Room.databaseBuilder(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), MovieDatabase.class, "db_movie")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build();
    MovieDAO movieDAO = database.getMovieDAO();
    return movieDAO.getMoviesByMovieType(1);
}

private Observer<ArrayList<Movies>> getMovies = new Observer<ArrayList<Movies>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<Movies> movies) {
        if (movies != null) {
            adapterFavMovies.setListMovies(movies);
        }
    }
};
}
```

I don't know it suddenly got me an error when I open my android studio again, previously nothing happened, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the doc is unclear, but you should always return a new fragment instance from `getItem` in your adapter. Inside [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html), `instantiateItem` is responsible to return a fragment, and it demands a new fragment instance if required:

```
// Do we already have this fragment?
String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
if (fragment != null) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
    mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
} else {
    fragment = getItem(position);
    if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
    mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
            makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));
}
```

In your adapter, the `getItem` will always return the same fragment instance. It's fine until the fragment is being destroyed when the adapter calls it the second time, which will eventually result an `IllegalStateException`.

Here's an example of how you can fix the adapter:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0: return MoviesFavoriteFragment();
        case 1: return TvShowFavoriteFragment();
    }
}

public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0: return getResources().getString(R.string.title_movies);
        case 1: return getResources().getString(R.string.title_tv_show);
    }
}
```